# Fulltext search multiple columns for multiple search terms

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement from a client to have a search-field where he wants to input any text and search for every word in that text field in multiple full-text indexed columns which contain customer information, from a customer information table.

So, for example, if he inputs `FL Diana Brooks Miami 90210`, he wants all of these terms (`FL`, `Diana`, `Brooks`, `Miami`, `90210`) to **each be searched** into the State, FirstName, LastName, City and Zip columns.

Now, this seems totally a bad idea to begin with and as an alternative I suggested using multiple fields where to input this information separately. Nonetheless, the point I am at is **having to** make a proof of concept as to why this won't work, from a performance perspective, and that it's better to have multiple fields where you input the term you want to search for.

So, getting to my query, I'm trying to write a Full-Text query to do what the client has asked for in order to get a benchmark for performance.

What I have so far doesn't seem to work, so I guess ***I am asking if it's even possible to do this?***

```
declare 
    @zip varchar(10)            = 90210
    , @lastName varchar(50)     = 'Brooks'
    , @firstName varchar(50)    = 'Diana'
    , @city varchar(50)         = 'Miami'
    , @state char(2)            = 'FL'
    , @searchTerm varchar(250)  = ''
    , @s varchar(1) = ' '

set @searchTerm = @state + ' ' + @firstName + ' ' + @lastName + ' ' + @city

select * 
from freetexttable(contacts, (zip, lastName, FirstName, city, state), @searchTerm) ftTbl
inner join contacts c on ftTbl.[key] = c.ContactID
```

The query I have above seems to work, but is not restrictive enough in order to find only the single record I'm looking for and is returning a whole lot more (which I'm guessing that it's because I'm using `FREETEXTTABLE`).

I've also tried replacing it with `CONTAINSTABLE`, but I get an error saying:

> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 26
>
> Syntax error near 'Diana' in the full-text search condition 'FL Diana Brooks Miami'.

With using regular indexes I have been able to solve this, but I'm curious if it's even possible to do the same thing with Full-Text.

Using regular indexes I have a query with a adaptable WHERE clause, like below:

```
WHERE C.FirstName like coalesce(@FirstName + '%' , C.FirstName)
    AND C.LastName like coalesce(@LastName + '%' , C.LastName)
    etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` with `id` and concatinated columns:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SearchView WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT  id,
        [State]+' ',
        [FirstName]+' ',
        [LastName]+' ',
        [City]+' ',
        [Zip] as search_string
FROM YourTable
```

Create index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UCI_SearchView ON dbo.SearchView (id ASC)
```

Then create full-text index on `search_string` field.

```
USE YourDB
GO

--Enable Full-text search on the DB
IF (SELECT DATABASEPROPERTY(DB_NAME(), N'IsFullTextEnabled')) <> 1
EXEC sp_fulltext_database N'enable'
GO

--Create a full-text catalog
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysfulltextcatalogs WHERE [name] = N'CatalogName')
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog N'CatalogName', N'create'
GO

EXEC sp_fulltext_table N'dbo.SearchView', N'create', N'CatalogName', N'IndexName'
GO

--Add a column to catalog
EXEC sp_fulltext_column N'dbo.SearchView', N'search_string', N'add', 0 /* neutral */
GO

--Activate full-text for table/view
EXEC sp_fulltext_table N'dbo.SearchView', N'activate'
GO

--Full-text index update
exec sp_fulltext_catalog 'CatalogName', 'start_full'
GO
```

After that you need to write some function to construct a search condition. F.e.

```
FL Diana Brooks Miami 90210
```

Became:

```
"FL*" AND "Diana*" AND "Brooks*" AND "Miami*" AND "90210*"
```

And use it in `FREETEXT` or `CONTAINS` searches:

```
DECLARE @search nvarchar(4000) = '"FL*" AND "Diana*" AND "Brooks*" AND "Miami*" AND "90210*"'

SELECT  sv.*
FROM dbo.SearchView sv
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.SearchView, search_string, @search) as c 
    ON c.[KEY] = sv.id
```

Comment: I just found your answer after I tested a similar approach. I created a new column where I concatenated all of the search columns (a bit redundant, I know - I like your indexed view better) and used a `WHERE CONTAINS(searchColumn, @searchTerm)` and it worked mostly. The only issue I'm getting is with e-mail addresses where it appears if I include an e-mail address like `abc@xyz.com` in my `@searchTerm` variable, I don't get back the correct line.